# cannot infer V: infer type parameter from constraint implementation

Tags: go, generics, constraints, type-inference

I have an interface in `go` which wants to support saving and loading results in different databases and I want to support different types.

```
package cfgStorage

type WritableType interface {
    ~int | ~string | ~float64
}

type ConfigStorage[K, V WritableType] interface {
    get(key K) (V, error)
    set(key K, value V) (bool, error)
}

func GetValue[K, V WritableType, C ConfigStorage[K, V]](storage C, key K) (V, error) {
    res, err := storage.get(key)
    return res, err
}

func SetValue[K, V WritableType, C ConfigStorage[K, V]](storage C, key K, value V) (bool, error) {
    res, err := storage.set(key, value)
    return res, err
}
```

I implemented fileSystem storage for this interface as below:

```
type FileSystemStorage[K, V WritableType] struct {
}

func (f FileSystemStorage[K, V]) get(key K) (V, error) {
    /// my code to load data from json file
}

func (f FileSystemStorage[K, V]) set(key K, value V) (bool, error) {
/// my code to save data as json file
}
```

BTW when I try to get an instance from `fileSystem` and `SetValue` it works, but for `GetValue` I faced a compiler error, my test code is as following:

```
var fileStorage cfgStorage.FileSystemStorage[string, string]

setResult, _ := cfgStorage.SetValue(fileStorage, "key", "value")
if setResult == false {
    t.Error()
}
var result string

result, _ = cfgStorage.GetValue(fileStorage, "key")
```

The compile error is in the line where I called `GetValue`:

> cannot infer V

If you have any idea how to solve this issue please let me know!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the function `GetValue`, it's not possible to infer the type of `V` with only the provided arguments `storage C` and `key K`.

You are asking to infer `V` from the concrete type that implements the generic constraint `ConfigStorage[K, V]`. The current type inference algorithm doesn't support this. Related issues in the Go github repository are [41176: cannot infer generic interface types](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/41176) , as well as [50484](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/50484) and [40018](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/40018).

Also relevant proposal section about [type inference](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#type-inference):

> We can use function argument type inference for a function call to deduce type arguments from the types of the non-type arguments. We can use constraint type inference to **deduce unknown type arguments from known type arguments**.

So you could argue that `C` is not actually known, you only know that it implements the constraint `ConfigStorage[K, V]`.

You must call `GetValue` with explicit type parameters:

```
// first string for K, second string for V
GetValue[string, string](fileStorage, "key")
```

Fixed playground: https://gotipplay.golang.org/p/KoYZ3JMEz2N